# Getting paragraphs between two tags in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to programming, Python and BS4 and I want to be better through a web crawler project. I have a bunch of similar pages with information that I would like to seperate. Here's a template of what I need to work with:

```
<h3>Synopsis</h3>
<p>First part of synopsis</p>
<p>Second part of paragraph</p>
<p>Third part of paragraph</p>
<p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer<br>
<strong>Directed By:</strong> Director</p>
<h4>Cast</h4>
<p>List of the cast in one line</p>
```

The "directed by" and "written by" information is really easy to gather but I would like to have the synopsis and cast paragraphs as well. The issue is that the synopsis is not always three paragraphs long on the site (sometimes less, sometimes more), so I can't hardcode it. My idea would be to use the word "synopsis" in the text as a starting point and  as a closing point and collect everything inbetween, I'm just not sure how to realize this. I tried to work with regex but I don't know it that much and I don't know how to work with html tags in regex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want everything shown in the grey box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<h3>Synopsis</h3>
<p>First part of synopsis</p>
<p>Second part of paragraph</p>
<p>Third part of paragraph</p>
<p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer<br>
<strong>Directed By:</strong> Director</p>
<h4>Cast</h4>
<p>List of the cast in one line</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

synopsis = ''
for para in soup.find_all("p"):
    if para.get('class') == ['writerDirector']:
        break
    synopsis += para.text + '\n'

print(synopsis)
```

output:

```
First part of synopsis
Second part of paragraph
Third part of paragraph
```

Getting Case needs a bit of hard coding:

```
cast_text = text[text.index('<h4>Cast</h4>'):]

soup = BeautifulSoup(cast_text, "html.parser")

cast_members = ''
for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    cast_members += para.text + '\n'

print(cast_members)
```

output:

```
List of the cast in one line
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that's exactly what I've needed and your code was really easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This may capture the essentials of a technique that does what you need.

You know that the content that you want begins with an `H3` element. Then you start looking through its `next_siblings`. Siblings such as empty lines ('\n') have the `sibling.name` of `None` and we can safety ignore them. This code displays the `sibling.name` and complete `sibling` for each sibling of the `H3` element. You have indicated that you already know how to dig out the contents of these.

Now all you have to do is to write code that notices when it has seen the `h4` element for 'Cast' so that it can arrange to read one more `p` element for the players in the cast.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <h3>Synopsis</h3>
... <p>First part of synopsis</p>
... <p>Second part of paragraph</p>
... <p>Third part of paragraph</p>
... <p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer<br>
... <strong>Directed By:</strong> Director</p>
... <h4>Cast</h4>
... <p>List of the cast in one line</p>
... '''
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> h3 = soup.find('h3')
>>> for sibling in h3.next_siblings:
...     if sibling.name:
...         sibling.name
...         sibling
...         
'p'
<p>First part of synopsis</p>
'p'
<p>Second part of paragraph</p>
'p'
<p>Third part of paragraph</p>
'p'
<p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer<br/>
<strong>Directed By:</strong> Director</p>
'h4'
<h4>Cast</h4>
'p'
<p>List of the cast in one line</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it was really useful to understand your way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than one Synopsis on a page (even if you don't) you can iterate over the soup and collect everything between the h3 Synopsis tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ="""<html><h3>Synopsis</h3>
<p>First part of synopsis</p>
<p>Second part of paragraph</p>
<p>Third part of paragraph</p>
<p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer<br>
<strong>Directed By:</strong> Director</p>
<h4>Cast</h4>
<p>List of the cast in one line</p>
<h3>Synopsis</h3>
<p>First part of synopsis 2</p>
<p>Second part of paragraph 2</p>
<p class="writerDirector"><strong>Written By:</strong> Writer 2<br>
<strong>Directed By:</strong> Director 2</p>
<h4>Cast</h4>
<p>List of the cast in one line 2</p></html>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
value = ""
start = False

for i in soup.find_all():
    if i.name == 'h3' and  i.string=='Synopsis':
        if start:
            print (value)
            value = ""
        print ("Synopsis")
        start = True
    elif i.text is not None and start:
        value = value + " " + i.text
if value:
    print (value)
```